# Why is this cfinput submitting multiple values?

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

Seems like this should be pretty straight forward, but I'm stumped.

Let's say I have a variable called "TheNumber", the value of that number is `123.56`. I want to display that number as a rounded number, or `124`. If I use the input code below, it will display as `124`, but when I submit the form it passes (`123.56, 124`) and thus an error.

```
<cfinput type="text"  name="MyNumber" size="3" value="#NumberFormat(TheNumber, 999)#">
```

I only want the `124` value to insert into the database. I've tried rounding the number, both in and out side the input tag, but I still get the same result. What am I missing?

Comment: it sounds like you might have two inputs both called MyNumber, one of them where you haven't used NumberFormat.  Which would explain why it appears as a list of two values.  Check your code, or post your complete code to this question.

Comment: Also you don't really need to use cfinput do you?  You can just use a normal `<input>` tag instead

Answer (score 2):

You have a second `input` with the same name in that form with the original value. Remove it.

Also, as Duncan says: there's almost no reason to use `<cfinput>` in this situation.

Would you consider posting your entire form to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for us to look at and suggest how to *stop* using `<cfform>` / `<cfinput>`?